# Running a service ignores environment variables

Tags: 12.04, services, environment-variables, nodejs

I have a `/ect/init/application.conf` file that looks something like...

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

export NODE_ENV=production

chdir /home/richie/application
exec /home/richie/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/node server/app >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
```

It is meant to run a `Node.js` application in production mode. However, when I run the application as a service:

```
sudo service application start
```

It outputs this data in the log when I output my environment variables:

```
{ UPSTART_INSTANCE: '',
  UPSTART_JOB: 'application',
  TERM: 'linux',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin',
  PWD: '/home/richie/application' }
```

As you can see, `NODE_ENV` does not exist in the list of environment variables. Any idea why my exported environment variable would be ignored? I also have added into my `/etc/environment` file:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like I should have used `env NODE_ENV=production` instead of `export NODE_ENV=production`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You're doing it wrong". In an upstart job, variables aren't set with `export`, but with `env`. So change your declaration to

```
env NODE_ENV=production
```

Things should work then.

Do note that upstart jobs are *not* shell scripts. They follow a declarative syntax. They *can* contain shell scripts but these have to be enclosed in `script`..`end script` (also, see similar syntax for pre-start and post-start scripts).

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html